# Problems with BETWEEN dates operator

Tags: sql, between

I am practising and experimenting with different syntax of SQL `BETWEEN` operator in regards to dates from the "https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp"

This is the `Order` table in my database:

LINK: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

The query is fetching the orderdates between a given condition of 2 dates.

These are the two main syntax versions (according to w3schools):

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #01/07/1996# AND #31/07/1996#;
```

and:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-07-01' AND '1996-07-31';
```

The output that we get on typing the above two queries from the `Orders` table

Number of Records: 22 (out of 196 records). Yes this is correct.

Now I am experimenting with this syntax versions.

CASE #1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN #1996/07/01# AND #1996/07/31#;
```

Result of case #1:  22  (same as the above syntax)

In the SQL try it out editor(https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_between_date&ss=-1) they are stating that this SQL statement is not supported in the WebSQL database.The example still works, because it uses a modified version of SQL.
WHY SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the W3Schools Tryit editor in Chrome, you're using [WebSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database), which is basically [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/).

SQLite doesn't have a date/time format, so is probably storing the date values as strings formatted in the ISO-8601 format (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13386693/9990662) for more information).

Other database systems (e.g. Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL) have built-in date formats, and you generally represent them as strings (enclosed in single quotes). For example: `'1997-07-01'` (depending on the specific RDBMS, there might be more specific considerations).

The format that uses pound signs (e.g. `#7/1/1997#`) is unique to Microsoft Access (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351259/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-number-signs-around-date-value-type) for more information).

---

Bottom line: Dates are generally enclosed in single quotes. You're best off sticking to the ISO-8601 standard (e.g. `1997-07-01`).

If you're learning SQL, there are other resources out there besides W3Schools. I would recommend downloading an open-source RDBMS like Postgres or MySQL, setting up a sample database, and working on some queries. Challenge sites like [codewars](http://www.codewars.com) might also be helpful

---

One more thing: Don't use `BETWEEN` for dates. Use `>=` and `<`, to make sure you're not excluding dates with a time portion. For more information, read [this blog](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).